# How to make an entity parameter private?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, parameters, entity

How to make an entity parameter private?

Now, entity parameter are like globals.

```
protected void ButtonSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var poProductDefault = new ProductEntity();
    poProductDefault.CGROUP1 = "5";
    string Name = "123456";

    DoSomethingEntity1(Name, poProductDefault);

    Label1.Text = Name;
    Label1.Text = poProductDefault.CGROUP1;   //Why "2000" ???? Is not "5"
}

private void DoSomethingEntity1(string Name, ProductEntity toProductDef)
{
    Name = "ABC Changed";
    toProductDef.CGROUP1 = "2000";
}
```

Comment: Why "2000"?  Because you changed the value in the "DoSomethingEntity1" function.

Comment: read more about objects in c#, and try to examine its' behavior, objects in C# are passed by reference, meaning an address was passed that is pointing on the same object in the memory. `ProductEntity ` is  a reference type, not a value type. Take time to read

Comment: What do you mean? Methods have parameters, entities don't.

Comment: I want to pass poProductDefault to DoSomethingEntity1(), after poProductDefault will not change value. like "Name" parameter pass to into DoSomethingEntity will not change on outside.

Comment: After read more about objects in C#, I think I ask error question title. Pass object as parameter is pass by reference, it can not pass by value. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C# objects are passed by reference, so your code is actually passing object poProductDefault to method DoSomethingEntity1().
To make entity parameter (I guess you meant to say property) private in DoSomethingEntity1() method, you can create another object of ProductEntity inside 
DoSomethingEntity1() and assign values from poProductDefault object and assign CGROUP1 = 2000. Return this another object of ProductEntity from DoSomethingEntity1() and from this object use value of CGROUP1 for assignment to Label1.Text

Comment: My poProductDefault will continue to do different thing. I would like keep its original value. Is it possible? Could you write some sample code? Thanks